# set customer attitude to required in one site and not on other site

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer-attribute, custom-attributes

In the multi-website, Can we set customer attitude to required in one website and not required in other website

Comment: What is customer attitude? I think this is not possible out of the box. Customer attributes are not meant to have different values in different stores, therefore I assume, that they are not expected to have different validators.